# How to run go test on all test files in my project except for vendor packages

Tags: testing, go, package

My project folder contains:

```
Makefile  README.md  component/  driver/  service/  vendor/  worker/
```

I'd like to run `go test` on all test files, e.g. `foobar_test.go` files except for the test files in the vendor package. The closest I've come to success was with `go test ./...` but that included vendor test files.

I saw in the documentation you can pass a regex to `-run` option but I'm having trouble getting this working. For example I tried `go test ./*`, but I get a bunch of `can't load package errors`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `-run` pattern is matched only against the test identifier (not the filename); in principle you could do:

```
go test -run TestFoo
```

but when you'd have to add `Foo` to all your test function names, which you probably don't want.

The `...` wildcard excludes the `./vendor` directory since Go 1.9, so you can now just run `go test ./...` and it won't include `./vendor`.

Answer (score 6):

> [cmd/go: exclude vendor dir from matching `...` #19090](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19090)
>
> [[go] cmd/go: exclude vendored packages from ... matches](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/golang-checkins/vendor%7Csort:relevance/golang-checkins/3nC41KX8NcQ/4L2CbiuNFgAJ)
>
> ```
> By overwhelming popular demand, exclude vendored packages from ... matches,
> by making ... never match the "vendor" element above a vendored package.
>
> go help packages now reads:
>
>     An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards,
>     each of which can match any string, including the empty string and
>     strings containing slashes.  Such a pattern expands to all package
>     directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the
>     patterns.
>
>     To make common patterns more convenient, there are two special cases.
>     First, /... at the end of the pattern can match an empty string,
>     so that net/... matches both net and packages in its subdirectories, like net/http.
>     Second, any slash-separted pattern element containing a wildcard never
>     participates in a match of the "vendor" element in the path of a vendored
>     package, so that ./... does not match packages in subdirectories of
>     ./vendor or ./mycode/vendor, but ./vendor/... and ./mycode/vendor/... do.
>     Note, however, that a directory named vendor that itself contains code
>     is not a vendored package: cmd/vendor would be a command named vendor,
>     and the pattern cmd/... matches it.
>
> Fixes #19090.
> ```
>
> [go / go / fa1d54c2edad607866445577fe4949fbe55166e1](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/fa1d54c2edad607866445577fe4949fbe55166e1)
>
> ```
> commit    fa1d54c2edad607866445577fe4949fbe55166e1
> Wed Mar 29 18:51:44 2017 +0000
> ```

Try running `go test ./...` at tip or wait for Go1.9.